# Number Input field, disabling users from manually entering number

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, html, input

I have a number input field for setting the expiry of an event. i.e. a user can create an event that expires in X days; the x is chosen using a number in put field.

I have set the number input field to have a min value of 1 and max of 7, but a user can still manually type in whatever number they want (i.e. 0 or >8).

I am trying to figure out a way to disable the user from manually entering numbers into the field without having to do anything with JQuery, etc.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

The app I'm working on is in Rails, but I think this is more an HTML/Javascript question.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will prevent someone from manually entering a number:

```
$('input').keypress(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CWadc/10

Comment: That's the kind of simple solution I love. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can limit valid numbers like this (for jQuery 1.7.x);

```
$('#id_of_your_input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode != 46 && // delete
       e.keyCode != 8 && // backspace
       (e.keyCode < 49 || e.keyCode > 55) && //numbers above keyboard
       (e.keyCode < 97 || e.keyCode > 103) // numeric keyboard numbers
    ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/ABYrK/1/)